# Jquery Print to display both the windows

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the `jquery.print.js` plugin.

Javascript:

```
 function printDiv(k,z) {

            var newWin = window.open('', 'PrintWindow', 'width=800,height=530,top=10,left=100,scrollbars=1,resizable=yes,visible=false');           
            newWin.document.open();//opening a Window
            newWin.document.write('<html/><body">' + k.innerHTML + '</body></html>');            
            $(z).print();//displaying Print Dialog
            newWin.document.close();

        }

function PrintButtonClick(){
  var printContent1 = document.getElementById('divMail1');
  var printContent2 = document.getElementById('divMail2');
  printDiv(printContent1 ,printContent2);

}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="divMail1">
        <div>
            <img src="image1.jpg"/>
        </div>
     <div>
            <img src="image2.jpg"/>
        </div>


    <div id="divMail2">
        <div>
            <img src="image3.jpg"/>
        </div>
     <div>
            <img src="image4.jpg"/>
        </div>
    </div>
<input type="button" value="Print" onclick="printDiv()"/>
```

In this, I am opening a window of divMail1 and Printing divMail2. But the When it loads Print window, the window.open gets minimized. I want to display both the windows.

Comment: Please don't repost the same question.